# (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, fetch

I am creating an application and when I try to upload an image it gives this error in the console: (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.
How can I solve this?

My fetch:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('arquivo', document.querySelector('input[name="arquivo"]').files[0])
formData.append('candy', candy)
formData.append('theme', document.getElementById('candytheme').value)

fetch('https://nodemae.herokuapp.com/candy', { method: 'post', headers: {'x-auth-token': window.sessionStorage.getItem('token') }, body: formData}).then
```

My server side:

```
async store(req, res) {
    let candy= req.body.candy;
    let name= uniqid(doce+'-')+'.jpg';
    let route= `/img/${doce}/`;
    let theme= req.body.theme;
    let sampleFile = req.files.arquivo;
    sampleFile.mv(`./public${route}${name}`, function(err){
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err)
        }
    });
    const candy = await Candy.create({
        name: name,
        candy: candy,
        route: route,
        theme: theme
    });

    return res.json(candy);
},
```

The return res.json (candy); returns this:{"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"open","path":"./public/img/paomel/paomel-q6zynjrg8w45y.jpg"}

[image]

Comment: what `Candy.create` looks like?

Comment: @Vadi 
Candy.create is just inserting into the database the path and type of the candy. 
it inserts into the database but the image is not being placed in public / img / candy / candyname.jpg

Comment: I think if you have an error it doesn't get inside this statement `if (err) { return res.send(err)  }`. This is why it pass to the final `return res.json(candy);` . Try to use log to make sure it gets inside it `if (err) {  console.log('about to send error '); return res.send(err)  }`

Comment: @Vadi 
I'm starting to think that the error is in this (err) but I can not solve it

Comment: you have an error related `sampleFile`, but you also have an error `Cannot set headers after they are sen...`, which tells that you do not get inside `if (err) { return res.send(err) }`. I don't know what `samplFile.mv` does, but `"ENOENT","syscall":"open","path":"./public/img/paomel/paomel-q6zynjrg8w45y.jpg` means that there is no file `./public/img/paomel/paomel-q6zynjrg8w45y.jpg`

Comment: sampleFile.mv is just a function of the express-fileupload package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because of this callback function

```
 sampleFile.mv(`./public${caminho}${nome}`, function(err){
    if (err) {
        return res.send(err)
    }
});
```

Your code sends response back from `res.json(candy);` while running synchronously, but when asynchronous callback is fired for, You are getting err and ` return res.send(err)

**Solution**

try this code

```
async store(req, res)
{
try {
    let doce = req.body.doce;
    let nome = uniqid(doce+'-')+'.jpg';
    let caminho = `/img/${doce}/`;
    let tema = req.body.tema;
    let sampleFile = req.files.arquivo;
    await sampleFile.mv(`./public${caminho}${nome}`)
    const candy = await Candy.create({
            nome: nome,
            doce: doce,
            caminho: caminho,
            tema: tema
        });

        return res.json(candy);
    });
}catch (err) {
    return res.send(err)
}}
```

Comment: this function is a controller so I had problems implementing this code, could I have a look? I'll add a photo to the question up there.

Comment: @HenriqueRamos try using await with sampleFile function I am going to update my answer

Comment: it still gives the error {"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"open","path":"./public/img/paomel/paomel-e995ednjrgba7sw.jpg"}

Comment: this is different error from one you were having previously. this one says can not open file in the given path.

Comment: also, before I was trying to solve this error and I came up with these 2 errors

Comment: check for the file if it is present otherwise check for permissions on the folder . You may have  permission conflict

Comment: my public is set to static, I have already tried to use ../../public${path}}${nome} but it does not work

Comment: its definitely folder is not  created in specified path ```./public${caminho}${nome}```

Comment: @ Henrique Ramos could you open ./public/img, what's inside?

Comment: in case, /img/${doce} is what defines in which folder the candy will be stored. http://prntscr.com/md8y9a

Answer (score 0):

An error occures while executing `sampleFile`. Other parts of code need to wait until `sampleFile` has finished. So you have two errors: `"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"open","path":"./public/img/paomel/paomel-q6zynjrg8w45y.jpg"` (because it cannot find a file) and the second one `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client...`  (because your code doesn't handle error and follows to the final `return res.json(candy);`  Try:

```
async store(req, res) {
  let candy= req.body.candy;
  let name= uniqid(doce+'-')+'.jpg';
  let route= `/img/${doce}/`;
  let theme= req.body.theme;
  let sampleFile = req.files.arquivo;
  sampleFile.mv(`./public${route}${name}`, async function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err)
      } else {
        const candy = await Candy.create({
          name: name,
          candy: candy,
          route: route,
          theme: theme
        });

        res.json(candy);
     }
   });
}
```

You can also use `then`, without `async` and `await`:

```
store(req, res) {
  let candy= req.body.candy;
  let name= uniqid(doce+'-')+'.jpg';
  let route= `/img/${doce}/`;
  let theme= req.body.theme;
  let sampleFile = req.files.arquivo;
  sampleFile.mv(`./public${route}${name}`, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err)
      } else {

        Candy.create({
          name: name,
          candy: candy,
          route: route,
          theme: theme
        })
        .then(function(candy) {
          res.json(candy);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });  
     }
   });
}
```

Try to use absolute path here `/public${route}${name}` for file uploading, because fileupload package doesn't use relative paths.

Comment: it still gives the error in either: {"errno": - 2, "code": "ENOENT", "syscall": "open", "path": "./public/img/paomel/paomel-1ceq3tnjrgcmbpg .jpg "}

Comment: @Henrique Ramos could you show what's inside ./public/img?

Comment: in case, /img/${candy} is what defines in which folder the candy will be stored. prntscr.com/md8y9a

Comment: @Henrique Ramos  try to use absolute path for your file path

Comment: ../../public/ ?

Comment: @HenriqueRamos like `/projects/glacebarbosaback/public/`, `projects` is just an assumption. Absolute path for your `public` folder and then `${route}${name}`